# Magento 2.2.5 - Add wishlist to custom new page

Tags: magento2, custom, wishlist, page

We have a separate new page for listing the products, there we need a "Wishlist" option as like as in product catalog page.

Can anyone share the exact idea to implement it?.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below steps.
1. Add below line for add to wishlist url.

```
<a href="#" data-post='<?php  echo $this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->getAddParams($_product) ?>' class="action towishlist" data-action="add-to-wishlist"><span>Add to Wish List</span></a>
```

And then after you can call script at the end of file.

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "wishlist": {
                    "component": "Magento_Wishlist/js/view/wishlist"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Thanks